# How to create a ssis project

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, etl, sql-server-data-tools

I want to use `ssis` to transfer database. I installed `sql server 2017` developer version. After installation, I could not found SQL Server Data Tools under the SQL Server 2017. Then I installed the `SSDT` for my visual studio 2017. I could not found the Integration Services Project in the `File -> New -> Project`.

Maybe when I installed the VS, I didn't pick `Business Intelligence` as the default setting.

So how can I create a `SSIS` and make a `ETL` package? I don't mind do it through VS or SQL server.

Comment: You should pick business intelligence as default template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open `SQL Server Data Tools` > `New` > `Project`. Then in `New Project` box, choose `Business Intelligence` from the `Templates`. There you can see the `Integration Services Project`. Select it and create the project.

Comment: Hi AsRa, Thank you very much for your helping. There was no Business Intelligence in my VS Templates. Then I installed the latest VS, and selected the  Data storage and processing and SQL Server Data Tools. The Business Intelligence is still not there. I am using the professional version. Any idea?

Comment: @psbookmark Are you sure your VS version is 2017? Because for prior versions, there used to be `SSDT` and `SSDT-BI`. The former was for building databases only while the latter could build SSIS/SSAS/SSRS solutions. From VS2015 onward they merged the two together into just `SSDT`, so after VS2013 there is no separate `SSDT-BI` install. I think.

Comment: Hi AsRa, I am using VS 2017 absolutely. But I still have VS 2010, VS 2013 on my system as well.

Comment: @psbookmark I am not sure about the issue here. But you can try uninstalling the versions you  don't need and then check if it works.

Comment: I download ssdt again, now VS has the business intelligence, and Integration Services Project. Thank you.